# Why can't function defined in vscode be called?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I defined a function in Python on Visual Studio Code, but when I call it, this error message comes out:

```
trin : The term «trin» is not recognized  applet of command name,
       function, script file or program executable. Check name's 
       spelling, or if an access path exists, check that the access 
       path is correct and try again.
At character Line:1 : 1
+ trin(1, 1, 1)
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (trin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

My script is:

```
def trin(a1, b1, a2, b2) :
    if a1 == a2 and b1 == b2 :
        print("The straight lines conincide.")
    elif (a1*b2)-(a2*b1)==0 and a1!=a2 or b1!=b2 :
        print("There is not intersections, the straight lines are parallel")
    else :
        x = (b2-b1)/(a2-a1)
        print("The intersection point is (", x, " ; ", a1*x+b1, ")" )
```

I deleted and reinstall vscode, Python and my other IDE/interpreters.

Comment: You didn't type `trin(1, 1, 1)` at a Python prompt, I think that error message came from PowerShell instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your post suggests that you tried calling the function `trin` directly from your terminal rather than from your Python file. Your function cannot directly be called by your operating system, which is why it is giving you this error.

Assuming your code is in a file called `script.py`, if you want to run this function, you need to call it inside your file, not directly into the terminal.

So I would suggest to edit your code to the following:

```py
# script.py

def trin(a1, b1, a2, b2) :
    if a1 == a2 and b1 == b2 :
        print("The straight lines conincide.")
    elif (a1*b2)-(a2*b1)==0 and a1!=a2 or b1!=b2 :
        print("There is not intersections, the straight lines are parallel")
    else :
        x = (b2-b1)/(a2-a1)
        print("The intersection point is (", x, " ; ", a1*x+b1, ")" )

# This will call your function with the given arguments
trin(0, 0, 1, 1)
```

Then, in your terminal, you can run your Python script using:

```sh
$ python script.py
```

This will run your script, which will call the `trin` function.

Answer (score 0):

You executed the python code as powershell command which is very clear based on the output you got. Hence, in vs code, as you launch it, you need to set python environment like the following:

- In top left vs code menu click on **view >> Command Palette >> Python: Select Interpreter** then click on the python version you will see.